# Why is a while loop much more efficient than a for loop here?

Tags: python, performance, benchmarking

I'm working on the Sieve of Eratosthenes and I'm analyzing how I could filter non-prime numbers from the range of candidates.

For testing, I'm using this command:

```
import timeit
print timeit.timeit(stmt="sieve(1000)", setup='from sieve import sieve', number=1000)
```

This is what I currently have:

```
def sieve(limit):
    primes = [2]
    pRange = range(3, limit, 2)
    while pRange:
        p = pRange.pop(0)
        filter_range = range(p**2, limit, p << 1)
        pRange = filter(lambda x: x not in filter_range, pRange)
        primes.append(p)
    return primes
```

Seconds => `5.42698788643`

I then thought that if I was going to pop the first element from range, I might want to write it like this:

```
def sieve(limit):
    primes = [2]
    pRange = range(3, limit, 2)
    for p in pRange:
        filter_range = range(p**2, limit, p << 1)
        pRange = filter(lambda x: x not in filter_range, pRange)
        primes.append(p)
    return primes
```

but it turns out to be much slower at `15.7085180283` Seconds.

Why is this happening? Is the for loop iterating over the initial value of pRange and isn't updating?

Comment: Are you sure the second one returns the right results? because you are changing the value of `pRange`, over which `for` is iterating...

Comment: you're not changing pRange inside the for-loop, but making a new list. And sure, it does not affect the loop.

Comment: **Is the for loop iterating over the initial value of pRange and isn't updating?**: Yes

Comment: @Daniel It passed the test cases provided to me up to a limit of 1000.

Comment: @KevinEngle: sure it does, but checks much to many numbers.

Comment: @Daniel Sorry, I meant to write that to mu regarding if the second returned the right results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for p in pRange:
```

This evaluates `pRange`, turning it into a list (Python 2) or a generator (Python 3), and then iterates through the items in the range. **It does not re-evaluate `pRange`.**

Either way will result in more loop iterations than the `while` loop would, because the latter is re-evaluating the range each time through the loop.

Remember, in Python, variables are *all* references. Even something like `a = 5` means "set `a` to refer to an integer constant with the value `5`." Likewise, `pRange = filter(...)` means "take the object that `filter(...)` returned, and set `pRange` to refer to it. Release the reference to whatever value `pRange` used to refer to (and possibly garbage collect it later if nothing refers to it)."